# subscript and superscript in ylab of qplot [R]

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried using expression(), which works with noraml plots, but my attempt below fails: any ideas?

I want to write: µg CO2 *(subscript 2)* – C m-2 *(superscript -2)* h-1 *(supercript -1)*

works perfectly:

```
plot(CO2~water_content, data=gases, ylab = expression(paste("µg ", CO[2], " - C ", m^-2, " ", h^-1, sep="")))
```

fails:

```
qplot(factor(vegetation_dummy),CO2,facets=sampling~biochar,geom=c('boxplot'),data=gases_PL)+theme_bw()+xlab('Plants')+ylab = expression(paste("µg ", CO[2], " - C ", m^-2, " ", h^-1, sep=""))
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 11):

your command fails, because the syntax is wrong

```
qplot(..) ... + ylab = expression(...)
```

you need something like '+ ylab(...)'

for example like this:

```
data(diamonds)
qplot(carat, depth, data=diamonds, facets = cut~color, geom='boxplot') + 
ylab(expression(paste("µg ", CO[2], " - C ", m^-2, " ", h^-1, sep="")))
```

Comment: i also had to replace "..." with '...' and then it worked!! thanks a lot!

Comment: The material inside that expression call is destined to be evaluated by the plotmath engine and therefore the sep= argument is not recognized as a separator and possibly would be confusing in its results if you pass anything except "". Try it with "-" or "_" to see what I mean.